# AngularJS 1.8x How do you $cancelRequest in a component?

Tags: angularjs

Apologies if I'm doing this all wrong. Trying to use a component that when instantiated it does my $resource GET but if it gets reloaded it cancels the initial get. The $onInit GET works great, I just can't cancel the GET if the user closes the modal and opens a new one. I can't seem to figure this out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

No matter how I try to place the $cancelRequest I get the error '$cancelRequest is not a function'

If I place it in $onInit ctrl.comments is empty every time this component in instantiated.
If I place it in the $onDestory then I get the '$cancelRequest is not a function'.

I'm using this comments section in a modal.

```
function commentsController($scope, Comments) {
    let ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        ctrl.comments = Comments.get({id:ctrl.item.ticket_id});
        ctrl.comments.$promise.then(function(data) {
            ctrl.comments = data;
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    ctrl.$onDestroy = function() {
        ctrl.comments.$cancelRequet();
    }
}

angular.module('app').component('commentsSection', {
    templateUrl: '/components/comments/comments.html',
    controller: commentsController,
    bindings: {
        item: '<'
    }
});
```

The $resource:

```
angular.module('comments.factory', []).factory('Comments', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('index.php/api/comments/', null, {
        get: { method:'GET', isArray:true, cancellable: true },
        save: { method: 'POST' },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE' },
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This code worked for me. This way if the user closes the comments modal and opens a different one the previous GET requests get cancelled.

```
function commentsController($scope, Comments) {
    let ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function() {
        ctrl.comments = Comments.get({id:ctrl.item.ticket_id});
    }

    ctrl.$onDestroy = function() {
        if(ctrl.comments) ctrl.comments.$cancelRequet();
    }
}

angular.module('app').component('commentsSection', {
    templateUrl: '/components/comments/comments.html',
    controller: commentsController,
    bindings: {
        item: '<'
    }
});
```